# Using iPhone resources in a C++ file

Tags: c++, iphone

I was wondering how you open a file in the app bundle from a C++ file.

I.E. I have a file "manifest.xml" that is begin copied into the app bundle.  I need a way from C++ to either load this file.  I think it is going to involve setting a path some where in Obj-C code so that the file is in the working directory.

Comment: ".. either load this file." - or?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use either CoreFoundation (C) or Foundation (ObjC). Every objects in your app bundle (the "Main bundle") can be accessed using `CFBundle`/`NSBundle` functions.

In CoreFoundation you do (NULL-checks omitted):

```
CFURLRef manifest_url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),
                                                CFSTR("manifest"), CFSTR("xml"),
                                                NULL);
char manifest_path[1024];
CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(manifest_url, true,
                                 manifest_path, sizeof(manifest_path));
CFRelease(manifest_url);

FILE* f = fopen(manifest_path, "r"); // etc.
```

In Foundation you do

```
NSString* manifest_string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"manifest"
                                                            ofType:@"xml"];
const char* manifest_path = [manifest_string fileSystemRepresentation];

FILE* f = fopen(manifest_path, "r");  // etc.
```